# Conditional contour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

The below code is what I'm playing around with at the minute:

```
x = np.linspace(0,30,1000)
y = np.linspace(0,30,1000)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

def f(x,y):
    return x**2 + y**2

Z = f(X,Y)


plt.contour(X, Y, Z, colors='black');
```

I want this plot to display some forbidden region, say when f(x,y) < 9; 
I want this shaded in and added to the plot. 
How exactly would I do this?

I've tried using `plt.contourf` but I can't quite get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do it this way using `contourf`, use contourf to fill with a solid color red then mask the region you want to display with your contour chart:

```
x = np.linspace(0,30,1000)
y = np.linspace(0,30,1000)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

def f(x,y):
    return x**2 + y**2

Z = f(X,Y)

d = np.ma.array(Z, mask=Z>9)

plt.contour(X, Y, Z, colors='black')
plt.contourf(X, Y, d, colors='red');
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: What has happened to the xaxis and y axis scales?

Comment: Whoops.  I forgot X,Y in those plots.

Comment: @ChristopherTurnbull Okay... check solution now.